# $scope variable is not getting updated on view which rendered using $state

Tags: angularjs

Below is app.js file contain myApp module. I am facing issue with $scope variable not updated on view file which is rendered using $state. 
I am calling showArticles function on ng-change event from one of view file which got rendered using $state.go statement. This view rendered after user login. All code snap given below. Also facing same issue after AJAX success response $scope not getting updated on view file.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        templateUrl: 'templates/setting.html',
        controller: 'adminCtrl', 
    })
    .state('profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html',
        controller: 'adminCtrl',
    })
    .state('account', {
        url: '/account',
        templateUrl: 'templates/account.html',
        controller: 'adminCtrl',
        cache: false
    })
    .state('articleList', {
        url: '/articles',
        controller: 'adminCtrl',
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: 'templates/articleList.html',

    })
    .state('addArticle', {
        url:'/addArticle',
        templateUrl : 'templates/addArticle',
        controller: 'adminCtrl',
        cache: false
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/settings');
});



myApp.run(function($rootScope, $state, $location, AuthenticationService){

    //array of route that dont need authentication
    var routeThatDontNeedAuth = ['/settings'];

    var routeClean = function(route)
    {
        //alert(route); alert();
        if(routeThatDontNeedAuth.indexOf(route) !== -1){ alert('aaa');
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }


    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, current){

        if(routeThatDontNeedAuth.indexOf($location.url()) < 0)
        {           
            if(!AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()){
                //$state.go('settings');
               //alert('not logged in and page is not login page');
            }
        }   
    });
});

myApp.factory('AuthenticationService', ['$http', '$state', function($http, $state){

    return{
        isLoggedIn: function(){ alert('Aut ser called');
            $http({
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/cUlI',
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(function(response){
                alert('testtt');console.log(response);
                if(!response.data.loggedIn)
                {
                    $state.go('settings');
                }

            })      
        }
    };
}]);




            myApp.controller('adminCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 'getArticleData', function($scope, $http, $state, getArticleData){

                $scope.addArticle = function(){
                    $state.go('addArticle');
                }
                // get website list     


                $scope.showArticles = function(){

                /*$scope.articleList = 'this is default article scope value';
                alert($scope.articleList)
                $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
                $scope.articleList = "Another value rest"; alert($scope.articleList)
            });*/

                    $http({
                            method: "GET",
                            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/articleList",
                            params: {
                                website:$scope.website
                            }
                            }).then(function(responseData){
                                if(responseData.data.status == 'success')
                                { 
                                    console.log('test dataaa');
                                    console.log(responseData);
                                    alert('page should modified')
                                    alert('This is test');
                                    $scope.articleList = {id:'test', name: 'article list'};//responseData.data.data;
                                    $scope.artLs = "I am testt model";
                                    $state.go('articleList', 'cache: false');   
                                }

                            })



                }

                $scope.adminLogin = function(){ 
                    var uname = $scope.username;
                    var pass  = $scope.password ;
                                alert(uname+'--'+pass); 
                    $http({
                            method : "GET",
                            url : "http://127.0.0.1:8081/adminLogin",
                            params: {
                                username : uname,
                                pwd: pass
                            }
                        }).then(function(response) {

                            console.log('succes',response);
                            if(response.data.status == 'success')
                            {
                                $http({
                                method: "GET",
                                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/webSiteList"
                                }).then(function(responseData){

                                    if(responseData.data.status == 'success')
                                    { 

                                        $scope.sara = 'testsara';
                                        $scope.websiteData = {id : 'a', name: 'test'}; // responseData.data.data;
                                        console.log('scope website data', $scope.websiteData);

                                        $state.go('account', 'cache: false');
                                    }

                                });


                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }
                        }, function(response) {
                            console.log('error',response)
                        });



                }
            }]);
```

showArticles functions get called on ng-change event from account view:

```
<div id="main-container" class="col-md-12  container" >
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="main-body">
            <div class="content"> 

                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Article Listing page modified</h2>
                    <div class="vt-add-article">
                        <button type="button" ="btn btn-default text-center" ng-click="addArticle();">Add</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vt-article-list">
                    {{articleList}} 

                    <br>
                    {{artLs}} -- exp value
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>

Main Index .html file :

 <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome to Vidarbha Tigers Content Panel</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/angularp/router/css/admin.css" />
        <script src="/angularp/router/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/angularp/router/js/app.js"></script>


    </head>
     <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="adminCtrl">
     <header>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="vt-header-content col-md-10">
                <div class="vt-header-logo">
                    <!--<img src="/images/logo.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="Vidarbha Tiger"> -->
                </div>
                <div class="vt-header-tag"><h2><!--Vidarbha Tigers--></h2></div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>

        </div>
        <hr/>
    </header>
            <div ui-view></div>
        </body>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Kindly let me know if I am missing anything in my code. I am new to angular js and facing few issues which are unknown to me

Comment: Is there an admin controller missing from your code snippet? (where are the addArticle() and showArticles() functions?)

Comment: It is already given in app.js file:

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: Don't think this is your issue, but I think you meant to do a comparison operation instead of an assignment operation with this line of code:
if(responseData.status = 'success') <-- *Note the single equal sign means assignment. Either way, JS should evaluate that to true and execute the code within that if clause. Again, don't think it's your issue but wanted to point that out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It was my mistake :(. I corrected code in post but still facing same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I understand your issue. Your $scope variable is getting reset everytime you call a view. Hence, you dont see any value. You will have to save the value and then retrieve it when your view gets loaded. I have updated your code below, try and let me know if it works or not

**SOLUTION 1:**
Create one more factory:

```
myApp.factory('persistService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){

var articleList = '';
return{
    saveArticleList: function(data) {
      articleList = data;
    },
    getArticleList: function() {
      return articleList;
    }
};
}]);
```

Then in your controller include the above service and save the articleList and when you go to your new view, intialize your articleList using the 'persistService' as below :

```
myApp.controller('adminCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 'persistService', 'getArticleData', function($scope, $http, $state, getArticleData, persistService){

           //Initialize your articleList
           $scope.articleList = persistService.getArticleList();

            $scope.addArticle = function(){
                $state.go('addArticle');
            }
            // get website list     


            $scope.showArticles = function(){

            /*$scope.articleList = 'this is default article scope value';
            alert($scope.articleList)
            $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
            $scope.articleList = "Another value rest"; alert($scope.articleList)
        });*/

                $http({
                        method: "GET",
                        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/articleList",
                        params: {
                            website:$scope.website
                        }
                        }).then(function(responseData){
                            if(responseData.data.status == 'success')
                            { 
                                console.log('test dataaa');
                                console.log(responseData);
                                alert('page should modified')
                                alert('This is test');

                                //Save your data
                                persistService.setArticleList('This is a test');
                                //$scope.articleList = {id:'test', name: 'article list'};//responseData.data.data;
                                $scope.artLs = "I am testt model";
                                $state.go('articleList', 'cache: false');   
                            }

                        })



            }

            $scope.adminLogin = function(){ 
                var uname = $scope.username;
                var pass  = $scope.password ;
                            alert(uname+'--'+pass); 
                $http({
                        method : "GET",
                        url : "http://127.0.0.1:8081/adminLogin",
                        params: {
                            username : uname,
                            pwd: pass
                        }
                    }).then(function(response) {

                        console.log('succes',response);
                        if(response.data.status == 'success')
                        {
                            $http({
                            method: "GET",
                            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/webSiteList"
                            }).then(function(responseData){

                                if(responseData.data.status == 'success')
                                { 

                                    $scope.sara = 'testsara';
                                    $scope.websiteData = {id : 'a', name: 'test'}; // responseData.data.data;
                                    console.log('scope website data', $scope.websiteData);

                                    $state.go('account', 'cache: false');
                                }

                            });


                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }, function(response) {
                        console.log('error',response)
                    });



            }
        }]);
```

Let me know if this helps!

EDIT::
**SOLUTION 2:**
There is another way you can accomplish the same just by making a change in your controller code. See below code:

```
myApp.controller('adminCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 'getArticleData', function($scope, $http, $state, getArticleData){

           //Initialize your articleList
           $scope.articleList = $scope.articleList || {};

            $scope.addArticle = function(){
                $state.go('addArticle');
            }
            // get website list     


            $scope.showArticles = function(){

            /*$scope.articleList = 'this is default article scope value';
            alert($scope.articleList)
            $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
            $scope.articleList = "Another value rest"; alert($scope.articleList)
        });*/

                $http({
                        method: "GET",
                        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/articleList",
                        params: {
                            website:$scope.website
                        }
                        }).then(function(responseData){
                            if(responseData.data.status == 'success')
                            { 
                                console.log('test dataaa');
                                console.log(responseData);
                                alert('page should modified')
                                alert('This is test');

                                //Save your data
                                $scope.articleList = {id:'test', name: 'article list'};//responseData.data.data;
                                $scope.artLs = "I am testt model";
                                $state.go('articleList', 'cache: false');   
                            }

                        })



            }

            $scope.adminLogin = function(){ 
                var uname = $scope.username;
                var pass  = $scope.password ;
                            alert(uname+'--'+pass); 
                $http({
                        method : "GET",
                        url : "http://127.0.0.1:8081/adminLogin",
                        params: {
                            username : uname,
                            pwd: pass
                        }
                    }).then(function(response) {

                        console.log('succes',response);
                        if(response.data.status == 'success')
                        {
                            $http({
                            method: "GET",
                            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/webSiteList"
                            }).then(function(responseData){

                                if(responseData.data.status == 'success')
                                { 

                                    $scope.sara = 'testsara';
                                    $scope.websiteData = {id : 'a', name: 'test'}; // responseData.data.data;
                                    console.log('scope website data', $scope.websiteData);

                                    $state.go('account', 'cache: false');
                                }

                            });


                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }, function(response) {
                        console.log('error',response)
                    });



            }
        }]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for alternative way. This solution works for me.  Is this natural behavior in angular js when routing through ui-router to lose $scope on view refresh? Because I observed if I don't change view and implement changes using ng-show with different section then $scope persists! Or is there any issue in my code because of which $scope is not persists on view refresh?

Comment: It is the way angular works. When a view is called, the controller gets initialized. In your case your controller re-initializes the $scope whenever a view is called as all your views share the same controller See my EDIT:                                                                              **Solution 1:** Is useful when you want to pass object between 2 different controllers                                                                    **Solution 2:** Is useful when you are using same controller in different views and those views share a object in the $scope(Your scenario)

Answer (score 0):

is the alert that you have put printing the correct value?

Based on my understanding I think you set the articleList on ng-change called in one view file. After that you change state and go to another view file where you expect to see the updated articleList value which you set in the previous view. But, I think what may be happening is that when you navigate to the second view your controller might be getting reloaded and your $scope.articleList gets reset. Try printing the value of articleList before and after you change view.

To prevent this you can try using angular services to save the articleList value

Comment: Thanks for input: Below are few details -

Comment: Thanks for input: Below are few details- I am facing same issue for $scope variable webSitedata as well. You can see in above code on success of adminLogin ajax call I am calling /webSiteList call which fetching website data and assigning response to webSitedata $scope variable but its not getting updated on view.   For articleList not getting updates, scenario is when user select website from dropdown ng-change showArticles  function called which in turn calling /articleList and after success assigning data to $scope variable articleList and calling $state.go to move to next page.